# Compiler Error C2766 while migrating c++ project from VS6++ to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i`m trying to migrate a C++ project from VS6++ to Visual Studio 2010 and get the error:

> Error C2766; explicit specialization "std::tr1::_Is_integral" has already been defined

it concerns the file xtr1common

does anyone know how to solve this?

thx in advance!

**UPDATE:**

the lines:

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;
typedef list<unsigned int> UIntList;
```

are "probably" causing this.

Comment: You need to give us a little more information. The line of code that exhibits the error would help.

Comment: There's no problem with this code in VS2010 for me. Even more information is needed. From the information on Google it seems that it correlates with the usage of some other libraries. Could you try to post a minimal example, eliminating as much of your source code as you can, while this diagnostic persists?

Comment: thank you guys for your help. i solved it by upgrading to VS2013 (from 2010).